# Re-rendering state in Reactjs not working as expected

Tags: reactjs

I have a parent component in React that holds the state of the application (I'm building a filterable table). In the state I have a the filters gathered by some inputs, the state looks like this `filters: [{"filter1": "value1"}, {"filter2": "value2"}, { }, { }, ...]`. The filters inputs are build in a child component `FilterBar` that receives the filters array as a propertie `<FilterBar filters={this.state.filters}/>`.
So when the user writes something in the input field it updates the state of the filters (parent) according to the field name and the new input value. So far everything works as I expected. But now I want to implement a button to clean the filters, so when the user click on it the state of the filters become empty (" " string for each filter value). I success on it, when I click the button it setState as I expected, and the table is updated as I wanted. But I'm doing some mistake, the input fields receive the new filters array properties but it doesn't clean the input text (so if I had a word or letter in the input text, it still there after the rerender, and I want the input empty as the state).
Here is the parent function to clean the filters (and I realize that it works as expected):

```
cleanFilters() {
    let filters = this.state.filters.slice();
    let f;
    for (f in filters) {
        filters[f]['value']="";
    }
    this.setState({filters: filters}, function(){this.updateData();});
  }
```

And here is the function that renders the text inputs on the FilterBar component:

```
renderFilterInputs() {
    var filters = [];
    for (let i=0; i < this.props.totalFilters; i++) {
        filters.push(<td key={i}><input type='text' className="form-control" defaultValue={this.props.filtersApplied[i].value} onChange={(evt) => this.handleFilterChange(evt, i)} /></td>);
    }
    return filters;
}

render() {
    return (
      <tr key="0" className="filters-bar">
        {this.renderFilterInputs()}
      </tr>
    );
}
```

I don't understand why the text input still save the text when I click the button because it rerenders again and the filter state is empty so the defaultValue of that inputs should be ("") empty. Thanks you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are using defaultValue not value means [uncontrolled component](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/uncontrolled-components.html). Default value will assign the initial value (default value) to input element only, it will not update the value.

**Solution:**

Since you are using onChange function with input element and updating the parent state also, so use [controlled](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html) input field, use value property instead of defaultValue.

```
value = {this.props.filtersApplied[i].value}
```

Comment: It works, but when I type something it have a short delay before show it in the input, is there a reason for it happens?